# Why is the unit of work repository i created causing a System.InvalidOperationException when inserting a new item

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, unit-of-work

After writing many repositories and interfaces for my data access i understood that ive been rewriting many codes over and over so i sought to understand the generic repository pattern and the unit of work. I followed the tutorial [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).
After implementing the example and incorporating the needed part to my project. I faced the problem of

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.
```

From my research i was made to understand that i could be using two database contexts hence the error. I have this GenericRepository class and the Unit of work class where i register all my repository below

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal ApplicationDbContext context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;
    public GenericRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }
    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;
        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }
        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split(new char[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }
        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }
    public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
    {
        return dbSet.Find(id);
    }
    public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (dbSet != null) dbSet.Add(entity);
    }
    public virtual void Delete(object id)
    {
        TEntity entityToDelete = dbSet.Find(id);
        Delete(entityToDelete);
    }
    public virtual void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete)
    {
        if (context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
        }
        dbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
    }
    public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
    {
        dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
        context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

Here is the unit of work class

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    private ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    private GenericRepository<Transactions> transactionRepository;
    private GenericRepository<PendingReason> penReasonRepository;
    private GenericRepository<DeclineReason> decReasonRepository;
    private GenericRepository<LoanStatus> loanStatusRepository;
    private GenericRepository<SalesAgent> salesAgentRepository;
   public GenericRepository<Transactions> TransactionRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.transactionRepository == null)
            {
                this.transactionRepository = new GenericRepository<Transactions>(context);
            }
            return transactionRepository;
        }
    }
    public GenericRepository<PendingReason> PenReasonRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.penReasonRepository == null)
            {
                this.penReasonRepository = new GenericRepository<PendingReason>(context);
            }
            return penReasonRepository ;
        }
    }
    public GenericRepository<DeclineReason> DecReasonRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.decReasonRepository == null)
            {
                this.decReasonRepository = new GenericRepository<DeclineReason>(context);
            }
            return decReasonRepository;
        }
    }
    public GenericRepository<LoanStatus> LoanStatusRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.loanStatusRepository == null)
            {
                this.loanStatusRepository = new GenericRepository<LoanStatus>(context);
            }
            return loanStatusRepository;
        }
    }
    public GenericRepository<SalesAgent> SalesAgentRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.salesAgentRepository == null)
            {
                this.salesAgentRepository = new GenericRepository<SalesAgent>(context);
            }
            return salesAgentRepository;
        }
    }
    public void Save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    private bool disposed = false;
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

In my the create action of my  controller i have a point where i use the usermanager object to get the id of the current user. In that point there is a reference to the ApplicationDbContext which i think is causing the problem. However i may be wrong. Below is my controller action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Transactions transactions)
    {
        using (var unit = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                MapTransactions(new CreateTrnVM(), transactions);
                unit.TransactionRepository.Insert(transactions);
                unit.Save();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.DeclineReasonId = new SelectList(unit.DecReasonRepository.Get(), "DeclineReasonId", "DecReason");
            ViewBag.PendingReasonsId = new SelectList(unit.PenReasonRepository.Get(), "PendingReasonId", "PenReason");
            ViewBag.StatusId = new SelectList(unit.LoanStatusRepository.Get(), "StatusId", "Status");
            return View(new CreateTrnVM());
        }
```

This is the MapTransactions Method.

```
public void MapTransactions(CreateTrnVM model, Transactions source)
    {
        source.TrnDate = DateTime.Now;
        ApplicationUser currentUser;
        using (var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
        {
            currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        }
        source.Agent = currentUser.SalesAgent;
    }
```

When trying to create a Transaction, This error keeps coming out

```
System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
    Additional information: An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.
```

A further research led me to this statement on this link.

> In a real application you’ll have to decide if you want to mingle your
>   data context with IdentityDbContext. One issue to be aware of is that
>   the UserStore class does not play well when using the unit of work
>   design pattern. Specifically, the UserStore invokes SaveChanges in
>   nearly every method call by default, which makes it easy to
>   prematurely commit a unit of work. To change this behavior, change the
>   AutoSaveChanges flag on the UserStore.

```
var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
store.AutoSaveChanges = false;
```

This still didnt work. or maybe something else is the problem.

Comment: In the MapTransactions method you use another DbContext. It can cause the problem. Try to rewrite it someway so that it will use your `UnitOfWork` instead of UserStore.

Comment: urg EF. the thing I notice is that your MapTransactions uses the DB outside of the unit of work. so the SalesAgent from the UserManager gets put on the transaction which is saved by the unit. Try passing the unit into MapTransactions and using it to retrieve the currentUser

Comment: @Ewan  i had a feeling that was the cause of the problem. I really need to be able to tie the item to the id of the currenly logged in user. Ive been trying to rewrite the code but no success yet. any help with a solution will be appreciated.

Comment: are you able to add the usermanager to the unit of work class as @alex and I suggest?

Comment: I've been trying and ive not been able to. I got this from a site "In a real application you’ll have to decide if you want to mingle your data context with IdentityDbContext. One issue to be aware of is that the UserStore class does not play well when using the unit of work design pattern. Specifically, the UserStore invokes SaveChanges in nearly every method call by default, which makes it easy to prematurely commit a unit of work. To change this behavior, change the AutoSaveChanges flag on the UserStore. "  I will try this now and make any updates later.

Comment: @Ewan no success yet. error still showing.

Comment: I wonder what percentage of c# questions are also about EF. My advice is you drop EF and use a repository pattern, sqlclient and transactionscope

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73836/discussion-between-ibnhamza-and-ewan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From various posts and research i finally got to know that the problem was that i was using a separate instance of the ApplicationDbContext as it was clashing with the one instantiated in the Unit of work class. This occured in the point where i was trying to get the User id of the current logged in user by using the UserManager class. A little research showed me this from K Scot Allen blog

> In a real application you’ll have to decide if you want to mingle your
>   data context with IdentityDbContext. One issue to be aware of is that
>   the UserStore class does not play well when using the unit of work
>   design pattern. Specifically, the UserStore invokes SaveChanges in
>   nearly every method call by default, which makes it easy to
>   prematurely commit a unit of work. To change this behavior, change the
>   AutoSaveChanges flag on the UserStore.

```
var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
store.AutoSaveChanges = false;
```

The suggestion above didnt help me but it drove me to find out more about the problem and i got to this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19571131/how-to-implement-a-unit-of-work-containing-the-new-identityuser) which  suggested that i create the UserManager class in the Unit of work class. Modifying my code above to include

```
private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
{
    get
    {

        if (this._userManager == null)
        {
            this._userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
        }
        return _userManager;
    }
}
```

I was able to get access to the UserManager class in the controller without using the ApplicationDbContext directly. I modified my controller like this

```
public ActionResult Create(Transactions transactions)
        {
            using (var unit = new UnitOfWork())
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    transactions.TrnDate = DateTime.Now;
                    var manager = unit.UserManager;
                    var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
                    transactions.Agent = currentUser.SalesAgent;
                    unit.TransactionRepository.Insert(transactions);
                    unit.Save();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                ViewBag.StatusId = new SelectList(unit.LoanStatusRepository.Get(), "StatusId", "Status");
                return View(new CreateTrnVM());
            }
```

Take note of this three lines

```
var manager = unit.UserManager;
var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
transactions.Agent = currentUser.SalesAgent;
```

I hope it helps other people.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on this line `source.Agent = currentUser.SalesAgent;`

You're setting an entity `SalesAgent` that was retrieved by one instance of `ApplicationDbContext` that is different from the instance that was used to get the `source`.

Comment: Let the UserManager be used the IdentityFramework and create your own repository the the user. That should solve your problem